# Subtract days from a date using Javascript within Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'd like to use a Javascript within my zapier.com-zap. Here is what I am trying to do for five consecutive days now:

I have a date (whatever custom format you need), need to subtract two working days from it and output it to DD-MM-YYYY using Javascript. Sounds really simple, but I don't get it to work.

Substract 1 day if original day is Saturday
Substract 3 days if original day is Monday
Substract 4 days if original day is Tuesday
Substract 2 days if original day is any other day

```
var date = new Date(input.date-zap),
formatted, daysToSubtract;

switch (moment(date).day()) {
    // Saturday = 1 days
    case 6:
    daysToSubtract = 3;
    break;
    // Monday = 3 days
    case 1:
    daysToSubtract = 3;
    break;
    // Tuesday = 4 days
    case 2:
    daysToSubtract = 4;
    break;
    // Subtract 2 days otherwise.
    default:
    daysToSubtract = 2;
    break;
}
```

This just doesn't work ;( Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zapier has an internal Action called "Formatter by Zapier" that will do this type of calculation for you.

Check out: https://zapier.com/help/formatter/#date-time

It looks like `input.date-zap` is being fed from a prior Action or Trigger, so you can add the "Formatter by Zapier" to manipulate the date and then use the output of that Action as in input your "Code by Zapier" Javascript.

May not be the perfect Javascript solution, but should get you what you are looking for.